# calling parent view method from sub view

Tags: objective-c

I have a ViewController which implements a refreshData method

In this ViewController, I add a subview by as following :

```
/* MainPageViewController.m
    //===============================================================================
    */

     #import "MainPageViewController.h"
     #import "SubViewController1.h"
     @implementation Drink4UMainPageViewController

    SubViewController1 *subViewController1;
    ......

     -(void)currentChatButtonMethod;
    {

        subViewController1 = [[SubViewController1 alloc]
                             initWithNibName:@"SubViewController1"
                             bundle:nil];


        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subViewController1];
      [self.view addSubview:navController.view];
        // viewController.

        CGRect rect = navController.view.frame;
        CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(320, -10);
        rect.origin = origin;
        navController.view.frame = rect;


        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Use a transform to slide it on.
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        navController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-320, -10);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

}

     -(void) refreshData
     {
     // CODE

    }
```

From here how can i call "refreshData" method in "MainPageViewController " ?

```
    /*
    // SubViewController1.m
    =========================================================================================
    */


     #import "SubViewController1.h"
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     #import "MainPageViewController.h"

     @interface SubViewController1 : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
    {



    From here how can i call "refreshData" method in "MainPageViewController " ?



    }
    @end;
```

I am adding a sub view from the Mainviewcontroller to UINavigationController now i want to call method (refreshData) in Mainviewcontroller  from Subviewcontroller1

Please help how can i do this

Comment: Your child view needs a reference to its parent.

Comment: Can you explain me in detail ?

Comment: Create a property on your child view controller and when you create it, have the parent view controller pass a reference to itself to the property you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child view needs a reference to its parent.  To do this create a property on your child view controller and when you create it, have the parent view controller pass a reference to itself to the property you created.

```
 @interface SubViewController1 : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
{    }


//Add this section <--------------------------------------
@property (nonatomic, retain) Drink4UMainPageViewController* parent;

-(void)DoStuff
{
    [parent refreshData];
}
@end;

-(void)currentChatButtonMethod;
{

    subViewController1 = [[SubViewController1 alloc]
                         initWithNibName:@"SubViewController1"
                         bundle:nil];

    subViewController1.parent = self;                     // Add this line<--------------


    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subViewController1];
    [self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

Comment: I haven't actually tested this so there may be syntax errors.